# App is crashing due to core data model

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am following the below tutorial to get my hands on using core data model.[tutorial link here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)

I have done what all said in it but I get crash from the app. please find the log below

```
LapTimer[3270:207] -[TimeTableController setEventArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d114f0
2011-07-13 15:11:32.369 LapTimer[3270:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TimeTableController setEventArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d114f0'
```

Comment: do you have declared the property for EventArray?

Answer (score 0):

Very simply you're trying to call the method setEventArray: which TimeTableController doesn't support. The most likely reason is you're trying to assign a variable called eventArray that doesn't exist or hasn't been synthesized.

Check your array is called eventArray and has been synthesized in your implementation file (the .m file).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you synthesize the variable in .m file,

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext, eventArray;
```

and also declare in the .h file,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventArray;
```